# How to request Notification permissions in Android app?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I need to request the POST_NOTIFICATIONS permission in my Android app. At least I think this is the permission I need; my goal is to receive a message in my FirebaseMessagingService subclass.

I can't get the app to request the permission. I have followed all of the examples. In every case, the callback returns false for permission granted without ever asking.

I checked to make sure I had the permission declared in my manifest (android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS). I also tried uninstalling and reinstalling my app.

I tried two separate techniques for requestion permisson (it wasn't clear to me why there were two, or which one was correct). One uses ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission() with registerForActivityResult and the other uses ActivityCompat.requestPermissions. Neither one worked.

I also went into Settings, enabled the permission manually, then uninstalled and reinstalled the app.

I know that many apps receive notifications so it must still be a thing that Android supports. What am I missing? Is starting with "FirebaseMessagingService" the wrong approach? It appears that there have been several different notification systems over the years with Android and I want to make sure I'm using the most current one.

Frank

Comment: What device and API level are you testing on?

Comment: It'd be good to post some code. We use `activity.requestPermissions( )` with only PostNotifications permission. With Android 13, you should also checkout showRequestPermissionsRationale (because if the user says "no" twice, Android won't ask again, even if you call `Activity.RequestPermissions()` again).  A rather confusing but seemingly complete discussion: https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting